# Spring-Boot running jar file for 2nd time causing timeout issue

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

Yes, you read it correct. I've done dozens of spring-boot micro service but never faced this issue.

I have configured spring security for secured resources. I do have normal non secured pages. I'm building jar using `spring-boot-maven-plugin`

1. Created jar file using `mvn package`
2. Pushed that file using `scp` to my remote server
3. Started application using `java -jar app.jar`
4. Everything works well. Just stopped the process
5. Did some changes on external properties, started again using very same command
6. Non secured pages are getting rendered.
7. Secured page redirecting to /login and it never render the login page. Causing timeout for the page

**Debug Logs**

```
2019-01-02 20:41:02.698 DEBUG 27713 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/admin/login]
2019-01-02 20:41:02.706 DEBUG 27713 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /login
2019-01-02 20:41:02.711 DEBUG 27713 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.admin.SecuredPage.login(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfToken)]
2019-01-02 20:41:02.712 DEBUG 27713 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/admin/login] is: -1
2019-01-02 20:41:02.789 DEBUG 27713 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Requested media types are [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8] based on Accept header types and producible media types [*/*])
2019-01-02 20:41:02.805 DEBUG 27713 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Returning [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.view.MustacheView: name 'login'; URL [classpath:/templates/login.html]] based on requested media type 'text/html'
2019-01-02 20:41:02.807 DEBUG 27713 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Rendering view [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.view.MustacheView: name 'login'; URL [classpath:/templates/login.html]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
```

**Spring security configuration**

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/stylesheets/**").permitAll().and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/register").permitAll().and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/js/**").permitAll().and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/images/**").permitAll().and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").successHandler(successAuthHandler)
            .failureUrl("/login?error=401").permitAll().and()
            .logout().permitAll().and().csrf();
            http.sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1).expiredUrl("/login?error=ms").sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());
        }
```

**LOGIN method**

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/login")
    public ModelAndView login(HttpServletRequest req, CsrfToken csrfToken) {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (!(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
            return utilityComponent.getRedirectModelAndView("cats");
        }
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("login");

        CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) req.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
        modelAndView.addObject("_csrf", csrf);
        String errorParm = req.getParameter("error");
        System.out.println("I am tired");  
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

And it is printing `I am tired` without any issues.

**VERSIONS**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>



<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>9</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>9</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
</properties>
```

**BUILD LOGS**

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1 (file:/usr/share/maven/lib/guice.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.admin:admin-app:jar:0.0.2
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------< com.admin:admin-app >-----------
[INFO] Building admin-app 0.0.2
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:resources (default-resources) @ admin-app ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 102 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ admin-app ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:testResources (default-testResources) @ admin-app ---
[INFO] Not copying test resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ admin-app ---
[INFO] Not compiling test sources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.21.0:test (default-test) @ admin-app ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.0.2:jar (default-jar) @ admin-app ---
[INFO] Building jar: /home/pasu/eclipse-workspace/admin-app/target/admin-app-0.0.2.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.3.RELEASE:repackage (default) @ admin-app ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.326 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-01-02T19:35:15-06:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Few application.yml**

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dna
  http:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 900KB
      max-request-size: 1000KB
  resources:
    cache:
      cachecontrol:
        max-age: 86400
        must-revalidate: true
        cache-private: true
server:
  port: 8080
  compression:
    enabled: true
    compression.mime-types: "text/html,image/png,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/javascript,application/javascript,application/json"
    compression.min-response-size: 1024
    http2:
      enabled: true
  servlet:
    contextPath: /admin
```

**Environment**

```
Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-38-generic x86_64)
openjdk 10.0.2 2018-07-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.4)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.4, mixed mode)
```

What am I missing.

Comment: Could you add versions please?

Comment: Updated @xenteros thanks for call-out

Comment: Silly question: what's the difference between `/login` (what you want) and `/admin/login` (which I see in the log)?

Comment: @paulsm4 `/admin` is context path. First dispatcher log prints full request URI, 2nd one 
 printing `@RequestMapping` resolved URI.

Comment: SUGGESTIONS: 1) stop and restart your app.  Probably won't fix anything - but it's absolutely the first thing to try before starting any troubleshooting session.  2) Set log level => TRACE.  3) Post back the trace-level info in your debug log.  ALSO: 4) Consider taking a Wireshark network trace as well.

Comment: Thanks @paulsm4 1) did that many times. 2,3) no helpful logs 4) Product not available for linux :S It's working after 15 mins. Not sure why it is behaving this way, so for new deploy I'm starting it in different port and checking health, if it's healthy, updating my LB with new port and switching. :(

Comment: Wireshark is most definitely available for Linux.  I use it myself :)  If you don't have a GUI desktop, or you can't use [Xming](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/), then try [tcpdump](https://linux.die.net/man/8/tcpdump).  ALSO: have you enabled Spring [debug](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html) and set loglevel to "trace"?  If not, why not?